# how does include work with soft links?

Tags: c++, c

I wonder what happens to quoted inclusion when included or includee are in the same directory only as a soft link.

Imagine three headers, `a`, `b` and `c`, and a directory `d`. `a` and `b` are in CWD and `c` is under `d`. Now imagine a soft link under `d` pointing to `b` (named `b`).

If only quoted includes are used and `c` includes `b` which includes `a`, will `a` be searched for in directory `d`, which is the location of the soft link to `b`, or the actual physical location of `b`, which is in CWD?

I've read [a page at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) but I could not find a definite answer. What is the meaning of "same directory as the file that contains the #include statement"?

Comment: I don't think C++ Standard mentions soft links.

Comment: soft links can be opened like files. They're not followed to find the original.

Comment: Why are you reading MSDN (Microsoft Developer Network) about the behavior of soft links? Those are a UNIX thing; Windows uses "shortcuts" / .lnk files which are more complex and not transparent.

Comment: @MSalters Windows has links as well, and these are not shortcuts. Look at [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) command.

Comment: Why dont you just create the files and links and try it yourself?

Comment: It was my impression UNIX soft links and Windows symbolic links worked similarly. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @pschill because that would only indicate how it works on my computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism to solve softlinks doesn't take into account the current working directory, but the directory at which the link is being resolved.  Let me demonstrate with a more natural example, if you try to read `/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h` (this is one of the places where the compiler is going to search for `<X11/Xlib.h>` in linux, for example) and it happens that `/usr/include/X11` is a soft link to `../../opt/X11/include`, the algorithm resolves to `/usr/include/../../opt/X11/include` (or actually `/opt/X11/include` finally, after solving all the path components), independently of your current directory.  Current or root directory are inode table entries that are reserved in your u-area (the part of the operating system resources devoted to your process) in order to initiate the mechanism or resolving the name to inode entry task, that finally deals to the inode of the file you want to open.  This is transparent for the compiler, so despite it has been said that it is implementation defined, it happens that all posix systems have a simple mechanism of a searching a system dependant list of directories for the final files.  But the soft link mechanism is transparent and you don't need to expect special compiler behaviour.

The only time wher the compiler will consider its current working directory, is if you actually force it to do, as in:

```
#include "./header.h"
```

or

```
#include "../../includes/myprojectheader.h"
```

## edit

in the case the soft link point to a file (and not to a directory) is shown with this example:

Suppose your installation has put the ncurses includes in one subdir (Let's say `ncurses`) in `/usr/include`, and you want to use `#include <ncurses.h>`, so you have arranged the following:

```
ln -s ncurses/curses.h curses.h
```

you'll have a link to the file `/usr/include/curses.h` which points to `ncurses/curses.h` then when you open `/usr/include/curses.h` the kernel arrives to the last part of the path (`curses.h`) and sees it is a symbolic link, so it substitutes the last part (as the pointed link is not absolute) and replaces it with `ncurses/curses.h`, and opening the file `/usr/include/ncurses/curses.h`.

Comment: your example treats the case of directories being soft links, not files. IMO directory soft links already makes sense (for as long as you don't locate other headers through parent directories). thx for the input though, one less question for later :)

Comment: @Andreas, the case with soft links is exactly the same.  See my edit.

Comment: It is the kernel that manages the softlink feature, not the compiler, the compiler even never gets the idea it has traversed a soft link to open the file.  Check that with a small C program that calls `open(2)`, and you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

The process of searching for a file to `#include` (whether `"file"` or `<file>`: [cpp.include]/2–3) is *implementation-defined* (except that the former falls back on the latter if it fails), which means that it must be decided *and documented* by your compiler vendor.  So it is pretty much “how it works on [your] computer”, although there are certainly common conventions.  I would expect the same-directory search to be in the directory containing the symlink, since positive action would have to be taken to do otherwise.